# Another student used my completed work, what should I do?

Tags: plagiarism, exams, cheating

I took a class a year ago, another student currently taking the same class had asked about my assignments to guide her in her work. I explained to her how intense the class is and sent her a copy of my work so she sees how much efforts she needs to put on that paper.

Without my authorization, she used my work for her assignment and now we are both in a mess. The school had contacted me about this matter and wants me to call them for a phone conference about this matter. The school policy includes but not limited to "no sharing of old assignment" or else disciplinary action will be taken. So how can one approach this case when asked to report by telephone?

Comment: Explain to the authorities exactly what happened, and provide as much proof as you can. Emails, chat transcripts, etc.

Comment: The policy includes "no sharing of old assignment", you broke this rule, now you have to face the consequences. Welcome to adulthood, were actions have consequences.

Answer (score 10):

If I understand correctly, the other student took the class *after* you took it, so it's clear that she cheated from you, not vice versa. I suspect they merely want to talk to you to find out exactly what happened. You are probably not in any trouble, unless there is a school policy against sharing old assignments, or the professor asked students not to do this, or you knew that she would have the same assignment when she took the class. So I would simply answer any questions they have, and explain why you did what you did.

Comment: Yes she took the class after I took it. The school sent me a letter stating that I violated the school's rule and regulation about sharing. I did not know the school is against sharing old assignment.  The student is currently on probation and now they are after me. Do you think they are going to place me on probation?

Comment: There's no way of knowing (without knowing more about exactly what your school's policies are, how the disciplinary process works, how convincing a case you can make, etc.).  However, you should take this very seriously.

Comment: I am taking this seriously. They sent me a link to review the school's policy and I just noticed the school is against sharing old assignment. I don't know what my fate. Is there anyway or particular thing I need to say while on the phone conference to exonerate myself from any disciplinary action?

Comment: There aren't any magic words to avoid discipline that I'm aware of. Explain what you did, why you did it, that you didn't realise at the time that it was against policy, but now you do and won't do anything like that again. Is there a student ombudsman or someone like that you can talk to?

Comment: Thank you so much! I do not know of anyone to talk to. This is an online class. I just need to find the right word or try to convince them that I did not share my work to cheat but to guide her on her own work. I do not want be short of words when talking to them. I have never been in a case before.  I will appreciate any help from this forum.

Comment: Presumably there's also an "evidence trail" that can back up your assertions. If so, I'd include that to show proof of your intentions. (It will also help if the assignment is one where the is no reasonable expectation that the other student wouldn't just turn in your work as hers.)

Comment: What actually happened was that she copied most of my work and submitted it online as her own work. The plagiarism checker detecte it as 100% originality from another student's paper, which is my paper. The school sent me a letter attaching the plagiarized work. They want me to report to them by phone.

Comment: So is there anyway to get myself out of this mess?

Comment: @Allyson If you have any emails between you and this other student that show that your intentions were not for her to copy your assignment, I believe that would help.

Comment: You need local advice, and random people on the internet who don't even know your school's policies or procedures can't tell you what you should do.  If your school has a strict policy against sharing classwork, then there may be nothing you can do but beg for mercy.  Otherwise, trying to prove your intentions were good may help.  However, you should expect skepticism: the oldest trick in the book is to let someone copy your work after announcing that they shouldn't copy it, so you can claim you never gave them permission to copy and had no idea they were going to do so.